# pdftex/pdflatex change directory of auxiliary files

Tags: pdftex, auxiliary-files

Have someone an idea, how I could get the output of pdflatex to a specific directory from `tex` to subfolder `temp?`

So that only the `tex` folder contains the `.pdf` file and the rest will be exported to the subfolder `temp` after compiling with an LaTeX Editor.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! With `latexmk` you could use `-aux-directory=` (on Windows). In any other case you could use `-output-directory=` and a shell script to copy the pdf.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you have a sample bash script for that. So it has to run in a for loop while working with LaTeX? With an IDE or editor in Windows where I specify the `-aux-directory=` in windows?

Comment: @noobcoder Welcome. Your comment's question depends on the specific editor. Nobody can answer something else except to tell you to search inside your IDE `Settings` or `Options` or similar place to find a 'build method' or `build command` and add an `option` there... but this is too general answer for a too general question.

Comment: Ok I understand I will read the editors manual. Has someone a bash script for me, that I could use with Linux or Mac OS?

Comment: really there is little advantage to do this, if you set things up so the aux file is in a non standard place you have to configure _everything_ else (tex, bibtex, makeindex, ....) to find it.  It is far simpler just to run latex in the build directory so everything gets generated there, and then move the pdf file to the desired final location at the end.

Comment: ok @DavidCarlisle that sounds complicated to me. Better a script that moves the PDF to another final folder :-). This could be the better solution or I move it manually when I am done. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: On Linux/Mac just create a symbolic link from the final place back to the build directory, so the PDF stays in the build directory and the link stays in the final directory and you don't need anything to move either manually or otherwise.

Comment: Good idea, or a script in any OS which copies the PDF to the final folder would also be possible.